# как удалить прошлое сообщение от бота

Tags: python, aiogram

когда отправляется сообщение 2 надо чтобы удалилось сообщение 1.
то есть когда жмут отправить вопрос надо чтобы отправилось сообщение и сообщение до этого удалилось

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='nextask', state=question.state)
async def send_ask(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    id_user = call.from_user.id
    username = call.from_user.username
    data = await state.get_data()
    text = data.get('text')
    await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, "<b>Вы задали вопрос, ожидайте...</b>", parse_mode='HTML')
```

[image: photo]

Comment: Код в студию!__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот это юзайте

```
await call.message.delete()
```

Comment: cпасибо огромное